# VBA: изъятие из столбца Excel номера телефонов различных форматов

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Было получено задание на изъятие номеров телефонов из столбца содержащего почты (Сами понимаете бывает создают что то типо 89999999999@mail.ru) с последующим переносом данных телефонов в отдельный столбец. Проблема в том, что везде они записаны в кривь и в кось, а помимо всего прочего требуется их привести в формат +7-999-999-99-99. Какими операторами это делается?

Comment: Функции: Left(), Right(), Mid(), Instr(), Len(). Операторы =, <>, Like.

Comment: То есть создаем условие и в оператор Like прописываем варианты искомых значений?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - вытащить подстроку до `@`, чекнуть на то, что там только цифры и записать их в нужном формате:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rows As Integer, i As Integer, email As String, phone As String
    r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.Count ' число строк '
    For i = 1 To r
        email = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
        phone = Left(email, InStr(email, "@") - 1) ' берем номер из эл. почты '
        If IsNumeric(phone) Then ' чтобы были только цифры '
            If Len(phone) = 10 Then ' если кол-во цифр 10 - вероятно, номер без 8 или 7 '
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "+7-" & Left(phone, 3) & "-" & Mid(phone, 4, 3) & "-" & Mid(phone, 7, 2) & "-" & Mid(phone, 9, 2)
            ElseIf Len(phone) = 11 Then
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "+7-" & Mid(phone, 2, 3) & "-" & Mid(phone, 5, 3) & "-" & Mid(phone, 8, 2) & "-" & Mid(phone, 10, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Вывод на тестовых данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `phone = Left(email, InStr(email, "@") - 1)` По-моему, `phone = Split(email, "@")(0)` покрасивше будет... а заодно не будет сбоить, если в ячейке отсутствует символ `@`.

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ

Comment: @Арсений если ответ оказался для вас правильным, отметьте, пожалуйста, галочкой напротив.

Comment: @Denis Ответ полжительный, однако типы данных на переменных пришлось заменить на Long по причине выхода за пределы интеджера

Comment: @Арсений у вас, наверное, много строк, в таких случаях да - нужен `Long`.

Comment: *ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1* - так правильнее, иначе при  UsedRange не с первой строки будет ошибка

Comment: *Long*  обрабатывается быстрее, чем *Integer, Byte*, поэтому  применять его выгоднее  даже при небольших значениях (но не на слабых машинах, т.к. памяти кушает больше)

Comment: @vikttur спасибо за замечание, учту)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант. Работа с массивами позволяет существенно ускорить обработку данных.

Если задать формат ячеек второго столбца *+0\ (000) 000-00-00*, то это позволит не преобразовывать число в текст и не делить его на фрагменты.

```
Sub test2()
Dim a()
Dim lRw As Long, lTel As Long
Dim i As Long
    With ActiveSheet ' лист, где нужно обработать данные'
        lRw = .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' последняя видимая заполненная строка'
        If lRw < 2 Then Exit Sub ' нет данных (строка 1 - шапка)'
        a = .Range("A1:A" & lRw).Value ' данные в массив'
        ReDim Preserve a(1 To lRw, 1 To 2)  ' добавляем поле для т/ф'

        For i = 2 To lRw
            If a(i, 1) <> Empty Then ' значение есть'
                lTel = Val(Right(Split(a(i, 1), "@")(0), 10)) ' извлекаем часть строки'
                If lTel > 1000000000 Then a(i, 2) = "7" & lTel ' номер есть'
            End If
        Next i

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        .Range("A1:B" & lRw).Value = a ' выгрузка на лист
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Хороший вариант, но не совсем подходит под задачу, т.к. массив нереально огромный, и там может встречаться разное .... кхм. В данный момент дорабатываю 1 первый скрипт, дописываю вариации, и показал он себя достаточно хорошо.

Comment: Доработал скрипт, и сделал ссылку на второй, который в теории должен редактировать значения которые имеются в в колонке и которые 1 скрипт не трогает.НО. Он не работает и выдаешь ошибку Application- Defined or object-defined error. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так? (Код добавить не получается)

Comment: ">> массив нереально огромный, и там может встречаться разное === тем более нужно обрабатывть в памяти. А то, что "разное":  для исключения/обхода/исправлений, нужно видеть примеры этих "разностей", чтобы составить алгоритм работы с такими данными. Универсального кода на все случаи жизни нет.